# Dask Dataframe error: 'Future' object has no attribute 'drop'

Tags: python, dask

I am new with Dask. I have created a dask dataframe, dropped some columns using the drop command. After this I am performing additional operations. When I call compute,  get error: 'Future' object has no attribute 'drop'.

Calling compute() immediately after the drop command works fine but when I call it few statements after, it gives me this error. Please suggest what is wrong here.

By the way, I am using dask distributed on my local machine and version is 1.2.1.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd  
from dask.distributed import Client  
client = Client()   
df = dd.read_csv("XYZ.csv", sep="\t",low_memory=False) #Its about 3 GB in size   
df = df.persist() #Data is split ito 47 partitions   

list_of_columns_to_delete = ['ABC', 'AXY', 'JDR']    

df = df.drop(list_of_columns_to_delete, axis=1, errors=True)   

df.EngineSpeed.mean().compute() #this works fine and computes the mean   
df = df[(df.Time < "23:59:59") ]   
df = df[df.EngineSpeed > 605]   
df = df[df.ServiceBrakeCircuit1AirPressure.notnull()]   
df = df[df.ServiceBrakeCircuit2AirPressure.notnull()]   
df.GpsSpeed = df.GpsSpeed.where(df.GpsSpeed < 111,111)    
df.GpsSpeed.mean().compute() #This gives 'Future' object has no attribute 'drop' error`
```

Kindly suggest what the error means and how it can be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I tried producing the error with a similar dataset and everything worked fine

```
In [1]: import dask

In [2]: df = dask.datasets.timeseries()

In [3]: from dask.distributed import Client

In [4]: client = Client()

In [5]: df = df.persist()

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                   id    name        x        y
npartitions=30
2000-01-01      int64  object  float64  float64
2000-01-02        ...     ...      ...      ...
...               ...     ...      ...      ...
2000-01-30        ...     ...      ...      ...
2000-01-31        ...     ...      ...      ...
Dask Name: make-timeseries, 30 tasks

In [7]: df = df.drop(['x', 'name'], axis=1, errors=True)

In [8]: df.y.mean().compute()
Out[8]: 0.00012229375505932677
```

I recommend producing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I was also able to use similar code on a smaller dataset and it worked fine. Is it possible that having more number of columns (about 200) can cause the issue?